# Modal displayed ONLY once after php echo

Tags: php, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to create a modal popup when user hits on a specific button but modal is displayed only once.I have two different `PHP` files.The second sends echoes `HTML` content to the other in a specific `div`.Below is the code of `PHP` second file:

```
 echo '                        
   <div class="row top-buffer">
     <div class="articles">
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <img class="img-rounded" src="'. $image .'" alt="MyImage" width="550px" height="240px"/>
       </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
     <p style="font-size: 22px;font-weight: normal;color:#7f8c8c">'. $title .'</p>
     <p id="article_p" style="max-width:550px;max-height:140px">'. $description .'...</p>              
       <div class="row top-buffer">
       <div class="col-md-6">
       <img src="img/link_icon.png" class="img-rounded"/>
       <a href="www.link.com"><span style="font-size: 20px;font-weight: normal;margin-left: 2%">www.link.com</span></a>
                                        </div>
            <div class="col-md-6"> 
          <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="label3">View Details</button>
                </div>
             </div> 
         </div>
     </div>
  </div>';

   echo '<!-- Modal -->
         <div class="modal fade" id="modelWindow" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
         <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
         <h4 class="modal-title">'. $title .'</h4>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
         <img class="img-rounded" src="'. $image .'" alt="MyImage" width="550px" height="240px">
          <p class="well">'. $description .'<p>

         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default">Close</button>
                           </div>
                      </div>
                 </div>
            </div>   
              <!-- End Of Modal --> ';
    };


    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#label3").click(function() {
    $("#modelWindow").modal("toggle");
    });
  </script>';
```

So there are 3 `echo`'s.The first for the content, the second is the modal and the third triggers the modal.As I said the modal is displayed **ONLY ONCE** and I cannot understand the reason.Do I need to include some `js` or `css` files in this file?Any idea will be helpful..

Comment: Have you tried putting your code to domready function?

Comment: It is the first time I use modals so please be more specific..

Comment: If you use the same ID to trigger the click event to display the modal, it will only work with the first / last of them. So replace the id for a classname and trigger the class name for your click event instead.

Comment: what is supposed to close the trailing `};` you have in your code? 
It might be there your issue.

Comment: `};` closes the `while...loop`.

Comment: @Nacho M. Could you provide an example please?

Answer (score 1):

Your code actually works just fine. I try to put together with fake content as below. Notice the js and css files I added to the HTML code.

UPDATED: I tried to put 4 buttons and 4 modals as that of your code. Not sure if you find this helpful.

```js
$("#label1").click(function() {
  $("#modelWindow_1").modal("toggle");
});

$("#label2").click(function() {
  $("#modelWindow_2").modal("toggle");
});

$("#label3").click(function() {
  $("#modelWindow_3").modal("toggle");
});

$("#label4").click(function() {
  $("#modelWindow_4").modal("toggle");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="label4">View Details 4</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="label3">View Details 3</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="label2">View Details 2</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="label1">View Details 1</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="modelWindow_1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Title 1</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img class="img-rounded" src="http://static.independent.co.uk/s3fs-public/thumbnails/image/2016/01/29/11/Taylor-Swift-revenge-nerds.jpg" alt="MyImage" width="550px" height="240px">
        <p class="well">Some description 1
          <p>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="modelWindow_2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Title 2</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img class="img-rounded" src="http://static.independent.co.uk/s3fs-public/thumbnails/image/2016/01/29/11/Taylor-Swift-revenge-nerds.jpg" alt="MyImage" width="550px" height="240px">
        <p class="well">Some description 2
          <p>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="modelWindow_3" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Title 3</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img class="img-rounded" src="http://static.independent.co.uk/s3fs-public/thumbnails/image/2016/01/29/11/Taylor-Swift-revenge-nerds.jpg" alt="MyImage" width="550px" height="240px">
        <p class="well">Some description 3
          <p>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="modelWindow_4" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Title 4</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img class="img-rounded" src="http://static.independent.co.uk/s3fs-public/thumbnails/image/2016/01/29/11/Taylor-Swift-revenge-nerds.jpg" alt="MyImage" width="550px" height="240px">
        <p class="well">Some description 4
          <p>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So I have to include these external files in the `head` of `secondfile.php` which is loading the content?

Comment: I think you got to include those files somewhere so they are accessible in your final HTML page.

Comment: I tried your solution.I have 4 button produced because I have stored 4 transactions but only the first 2 buttons trigger the modal.The other 2 show nothing..

Comment: Are the 4 buttons/modals the same as that you showed or can you check if there is anything different among them?

Comment: Then make sure the button IDs and modal IDs are unique :)

Comment: It could be helpful but everything is depending on how many transactions are stored in the database..If I had 100 or 1000 transactions?